# Creating Outlook Tasks with Python

Tags: python, automation, outlook, ms-office

Is there a way using Python to automate adding Tasks to Outlook (2007 or 2010)?  I see there is a way to create Outlook Invites through pywin32, however, I'm not sure about the parameters required, and I couldn't find any relevant docs that outline the parameter/value requirements (although I'm sure they're out there).

Thanks!

Comment: What does `dir <<object>>` tell you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this one, sorry. Dir in what context?

Comment: `dir` is a built-in python function which you can use to display the methods and attributes of an object. That way you can find out more about how to use it, even when there is no or little documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [snippet](http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/266/284/) but I am not sure if that really works because I have not installed Outlook. And it requires a Taskcoach task file. But maybe you will get new ideas and some inspiration through this example.

Comment: Interesting.  Since it looks like the Taskcoach stuff is just used as input, I can largely ignore it and just play with how the tasks are built.  Thanks!